# Get total number of post views of all posts from a user in laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get the total number of views of all posts from each user and display it to the user dashboard.

I added a "reads" column to my article migration.

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigInteger('reads')->default(0)->index();
        });
    }
```

I have a method in my Article (post) Model called incrementReadCount() which counts the views of each article.

```
public function incrementReadCount() 
    {
        $this->reads++;
        return $this->save();
    }
```

In my ArticlesController I display the number of views on an article

```
public function show(Article $article, User $user)
{
    $articles = $user->articles()->get();

    if(Cookie::get($article->id)!=''){
        Cookie::set('$article->id', '1', 60);
        $article_reads = $article->incrementReadCount();
    }
    return view('article.article', compact('article','user', 'articles', 'article_reads'));
}
```

How do I display the total number of all article views on the user dashboard? My home controller:

```
public function index(User $user, Article $article)
{

    return view('dashboard', compact('user', 'article'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your index method, grab all user's articles and do a summation over "reads" column:

```
$user->articles()->sum('reads');
```

Comment: `$total_views = $user->articles->sum('reads');
  return view('dashboard', compact('user', 'article', 'total_views'));` always returns 0 views

Comment: Are you sure the reads column getting incremented in the articles table?